# jQuery sortable cancel and move the item back with animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I was searching for how to cancel a sortable item on drop and reject.
I found the solution:

```
receive: function(event, ui){
if(condition) {
    //do something here
    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
}
```

The item is moved to its original position.
But I want the item to move to its original position back with animation.
Please help.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-revert

Comment: @apaul34208 revert is working when elements are dragged. but when I try to cancel a dropped item in receive function using ui.sender.sortable("cancel"), the item is being moved but not with animation. I want it moved back with animation. please help.

Comment: It appears that this is a know bug that they don't intend to fix: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9425